# VMware CentOS message

Tags: centos

I want to install Centos 6.8 to VMware, but it shows me this message [here](http://www.picpaste.com/centos_6.8-CvElpRP1.jpg)

Does it mean that it will erase data on my hdd?

Answer (score 0):

When you were creating your new virtual machine, you set aside what looks to be 25GB as the virtual hard drive of that machine. The CentOS installation will only format/partition that set-aside 25GB and it will not affect any other data on your host machine. You can safely click Yes in that window without worrying about erasing other data on the drive.

Comment: The same happens with Kali linux here ?????    http://www.picpaste.com/kali_linux-KZOUgIRI.jpg